# Tengo un error con next, no me levanta la app. Dice que es un error de expresion regular

Tags: javascript, webpack, next

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at exports.init (/home/edgar/Workspace/Platzi2023/next/migolilla/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/webpack.js:24:28)
at Object.loadWebpackHook (/home/edgar/Workspace/Platzi2023/next/migolilla/node_modules/next/dist/server/config-utils.js:14:5)

Comment: Hola edgarlopez241, Para que podamos ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar),

Comment: no habia escrito ningun codigo, solo instale las dependencias para probar next, y este no me levanta. Estoy usando so, ubuntu 22.